# Rails application + Sidekiq in different instances on AWS/EBS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Rails application deployed with Puma in one EBS instance. All tutorials I've read deploys Sidekiq to the same instance as the web server.

How do I deploy Sidekiq( using the same application ) to a different instance? Can I specify a config file for a specific instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Worker "dyno" in AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214876/worker-dyno-in-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: @Jirico why do you need it?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/ThoughtWorksStudios/eb_deployer - personally I couldn't get Rails to work smoothly on Beanstalk due to a number of reasons but maybe things have improved since then.

Comment: @NeverBe Because it's safer to use Sidekiq separately. If some job eats all memory webserver keeps working.

Comment: run 2 envs  maybe, 1st - balancer + n instaces, 2nd - single instance for sidekiq (no migrations/no assets compilation)

Comment: Have you tried capistrano? It can make this kind of deployment pretty easy.  Plus 
@NeverBe comment is on point.

Comment: I use a variation of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ssaunier/44bbebb9c0fa01953860) to run Sidekiq on an EB worker for my projects. I modified the script to only boot sidekiq when a particular environment variable is present on the worker environment (so it won't run on the webserver).

Comment: Looks like Sidekiq on EBS can not be configured and work smoothly as a by hand configuration. So for now, I'll configure my own EC2 instance to run Sidekiq.

Comment: Hi @Jirico, are you running Sidekiq server on same instance or separate one?